# XCode Codesigning Issue

Tags: ios, xcode8, code-signing-certificate

I have questions concerning codesigning for the iOS app.

While we archive the app developed in XCode,
it will code sign the app for once before the Organizer windows pop up and show the archive history.

For Example:
[image]

We can see that the app was signed which we can know signing identity and provisioning profile by looking into the log for archive.

But when we export the app in Organizer Window, for example export for ad hoc deployment, and following window show the details for the export,
[image]

This Window also show the provisioning profile, but different from the one that i see from log. (which i set the provisioning profile which shown in the log as the release provisioning profile in Build Settings)

May i ask are these two provisioning profile same thing? Can i use different pp when i export the archived app as ipa?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use different provisioning profiles between your build/archive and when you export them.

If you look in the right side of the organizer window, you'll see the "Upload to App Store..." button over the "Export..." button.  The organizer re-codesigns your archived app with your App Store distribution certificate if you are uploading that version into the store or TestFlight review, or you can export that binary for ADHOC distribution (to specified devices), Enterprise distribution (distributing within your company) or a development version to people on your team that have the development certificates installed.

If you select ADHOC, you have the choice between Automatically Signing (which is the "XC iOS ADHOC" cert you see in that window or Manually (i.e. here is where you can choose from different provisioning profiles:
[image: multiple provisioning profiles]
In real life, you'll really want to have your provisioning profile named two different things so you'll know what you're really setting the app to.

Comment: I don't know why i can't choose the provisioning profile used to export the app :'(, btw thanks for your reply :)

Comment: There's a number of different settings in play here (e.g. try unchecking the "automatically manage signing" checkmark that's set to on in your Target's "General" settings?).

Comment: My setting for "automatically manage signing" has already unchecked

Answer (score 0):

It is depend upon the type of provisioning you are using for type of job.

**Development :**

If you want to create .ipa file just to installed in to the registered device you have to choose development provisioning profile.

**Adhoc :**

If you want to distribute the app through 3rd party like [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)It is suggested to use Adhoc provisioning.

**App Store distribution :**

For Test flight release or if you want to upload the binary to app store it required distribution provisioning profile with distribution certificate.

Now you are triggering your issue because of mismatching purpose and profile. 
please create valid provisioning as per your requirement .

Let me know if this works.